How can I update my Firefox .desktop file so that it properly launches?
Summary
I recently removed the Firefox snap and replaced it with the .deb version of the program. The Application Launcher is finding a Firefox entry, but will not launch when I click it.
System Details

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS, 64-bit
Firefox version: Debian package, version 131.0 (64-bit)

Steps to reproduce

Uninstall Firefox snap via sudo snap remove firefox
Install Firefox .deb as per these instructions
Press the Super/Windows key to open the Application Launcher
Type "firefox"
Click "Firefox Web Browser" that shows up.

Expected behavior
Firefox launches.
Actual behavior
Firefox does not launch.
Extra details
which firefox says that the program can be found at /usr/bin/firefox. The content of /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop is long, but contains the following Exec values (for different entries):
Exec=firefox %u
...
Exec=firefox --new-window %u
...
Exec=firefox --private-window %u
...
Exec=firefox --ProfileManager

If I use the alacarte application to edit the menu entry for Firefox Web Browser, the "Command" field contains env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/firefox_firefox.desktop /snap/bin/firefox %u. However, when I try to edit the content of that field to firefox %u, although the "OK" button is not disabled, clicking it does nothing—the dialog remains open, unsaved. There appears to be a disconnect between the /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop file and what alacarte is referencing, and I can't figure out how to change what's in alacarte.
Please help me understand how to make changes that are reflected in my Application Launcher, so I can launch the .deb version of Firefox that was installed at /usr/bin/firefox.

You may have a firefox.desktop in ~/.local/share/applications/ which superseeds the file in /usr/share/application. If so, move the file in ~/.local/share/applications/ to the trash and check if your problem is solved then.

Ah, amazing, thank you. I didn't realize there was a second location at ~/.local/share/applications, that made a difference. I'm going to repost this as an answer and mark it as a solution, but this did the trick.

Solution
There were two related firefox.desktop files (well, technically, one firefox.desktop and one firefox_firefox.desktop) in ~/.local/share/applications/, which took precedence over the files in /usr/share/applications.
I deleted those two files in ~/.local/share/applications/, and the launcher now works as expected.
